# Crashed app randomly when lock device with Android 10

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer, android-10.0

I have an app in first device (client) which has p2p connection with other device (server). Server streaming a video to client. When I lock device-client sometimes it cause crashing app, sometimes it works correctly.

In case when client app crashed thrown this exception:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c in tid 9072
```

Tombstone:

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m01qser/m01q:10/QP1A.190711.020/M015FXXS2ATL1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
Timestamp: 2021-01-19 10:47:45+0300
pid: 12289, tid: 12289, name: client  >>> com.client <<<
uid: 10200
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c
Cause: null pointer dereference
    r0  00000000  r1  ffbff2cc  r2  00000000  r3  00000000
    r4  dea2c88d  r5  1809d588  r6  1809d5b8  r7  1809d5b8
    r8  00000000  r9  f0940800  r10 ffbff2d0  r11 f0940800
    ip  bd7c45c1  sp  ffbff2b0  lr  ebefa51b  pc  bd7c45c2

backtrace:
  #00 pc 000b15c2  /data/app/com.kbnt.naparnik.client-_jyhSqNMJOJnAVSyrHHC-A==/base.apk!libgstreamer_android.so (offset 0x173000)
  #01 pc 000dc519  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #02 pc 0201f981  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (org.freedesktop.gstreamer.androidmedia.GstAmcOnFrameAvailableListener.onFrameAvailable+64)
  #03 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #04 pc 00436af5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+252) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #05 pc 000dffeb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+178) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #06 pc 00213875  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #07 pc 0020f18d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+716) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #08 pc 0042d1cf  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+814) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #09 pc 000d2a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #10 pc 00403c90  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1.handleMessage+8)
  #11 pc 0042bfa1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1192) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #12 pc 000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #13 pc 00358796  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
  #14 pc 0042bfa1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1192) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #15 pc 000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #16 pc 00398916  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.os.Looper.loop+466)
  #17 pc 0042e515  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+932) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #18 pc 000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #19 pc 001a7704  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main+208)
  #20 pc 001eeb79  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.4474381389789028307+192) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #21 pc 001f336b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #22 pc 004205dd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+852) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #23 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #24 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #25 pc 00436c09  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+248) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #26 pc 000dffff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+198) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #27 pc 00377a3b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #28 pc 00378f55  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+932) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #29 pc 0032450b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+30) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #30 pc 000bc8b7  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+110) (BuildId: df82c1442bb900522d178526344bb1a19782e73e)
  #31 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #32 pc 00436af5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+252) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #33 pc 000dffeb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+178) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #34 pc 00213875  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #35 pc 0020f18d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+716) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #36 pc 0042bd55  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+604) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #37 pc 000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #38 pc 0048ba16  /system/framework/framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
  #39 pc 001eeb79  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.4474381389789028307+192) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #40 pc 001f336b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #41 pc 004205dd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+852) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #42 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #43 pc 0082a471  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2512) (BuildId: 1c45c1313304c9882a73dc0dd91dfb79573cced2)
  #44 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #45 pc 00436c09  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+248) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #46 pc 000dffff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+198) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #47 pc 00377a3b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #48 pc 003777f1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+292) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #49 pc 002c1539  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+460) (BuildId: f186f2720d2bb2094a21740d06192831)
  #50 pc 000a2351  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+28) (BuildId: f6f68fcd9de2f0c891b7538cb595d5ce)
  #51 pc 000a48d9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+508) (BuildId: f6f68fcd9de2f0c891b7538cb595d5ce)
  #52 pc 0000230f  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+714) (BuildId: ad621c21d45a1415057675aef975671e)
  #53 pc 0005a2e1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+68) (BuildId: 6b958cfe24f2450b4242d6f7da7559ba)
  #54 pc 0000202f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38) (BuildId: ad621c21d45a1415057675aef975671e)
  #55 pc 00004456  <anonymous:f0f19000>
```

Does someone have idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Since this is gstreamer, a wild guess is you're drawing to a surface which has been destroyed.

Comment: @codeconscious But it happens randomly. I can lock phone several times and 4 of 10 attempts app crashes.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @MuratAKSU Yes, I did. But I don't sure why it happens. Changing battery mode on server(Xiaomi) and client(Samsung) to "no restrictions" helps me. 
Also, on Xiaomi need to add your app to "no restriction" list:
Settings -> Battery & performance -> App battery saver -> Select your app -> Select "No restrictions"

Comment: @MuratAKSU When I use Samsung like a server and client, app also crashes randomly. May be Samsung makes some battery optimization which destroy surface sometime

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was directly related to database inspector.

Solution:

1- Restart Android Studio.

2- Dont click "Database Inspector" tab.

Note: There is no way to close the database inspactor once you open it. You need to restart Android Studio.